# Using XSD.exe to generate classes from a Schema with IEnumerable instead of an Array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xsd, xsd.exe

I am using XSD.exe to generate a set of .NET classes that will map to my XSD schema.  One thing I would like is to have repeated elements of a sequence mapped in the new classes as an IEnumerable instead of Array.

Here is a snipped of the XSD schema:

```
<xs:element name="Locations">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Location" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

This will generate my Locations class with a Location property which is of type **Location[]**.  (An array).

I would much rather it generate as `IEnumerable<Location>`.  This would make using the generated classes much simpler.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: No, it wasn't worth the cost of implementing a solution for this versus with living with an array.

Answer (score 0):

In short, No.
Have a look at xsd2code which allows you the generate `List<Location>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsd2code (give it a try !), or maybe use "svcutil.exe" rather than xsd.exe, which if I remind well could bo applied to XSDs and allows to pass switches like this : /collectionType:System.Collections.Generic.List`1